# error on mpi scatterv with long displacements

Tags: c, mpi

I'm using MPI_Scatterv to scatter a very large array:

```
MPI_Scatterv(list, counts, displacements, MPI_LONG, pSubList, counts[rank], MPI_LONG, MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

and I've declared the variables **counts** and **displacements** as long (the int type is not enough), however, the MPI_Scatterv only accepts int variables for counts and displacements.

Any idea on how can I somehow solve this?

Comment: The best I could find is to recompile MPI with 64-bit support http://diracprogram.org/doc/release-12/installation/int64/mpi.html#open-mpi-with-64-bit-integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't substitute long for int, at least not in most MPI 2.2 implementations. Even if you create a user defined datatype as advised by Greg, you might (and mostly will) run into implementation limitations like using integer to represent offsets internally. The MPI 3.0 draft has specifically addressed this issue and requires that offset and count parameters be of long (64-bit) type in both C and Fortran bindings.

Until MPI 3.0 becomes standard and conformant implementations are out I would stick with some subcommunication scheme like distributing the data in several rounds with multiple scatters to subsets of ranks.

Comment: Apparently this was not followed, at least it was not forced. I am using a couple of implementations of MPI-3 in 2019 and the header files still have `int` in the displacement arguments. The most you can do is recompile openmpi to get 64-bit offsets. http://diracprogram.org/doc/release-12/installation/int64/mpi.html#open-mpi-with-64-bit-integers

Comment: @alfC, the long counts never made it into the MPI specification, unfortunately. The rationale iirc was that `long` params break existing software and that most times one can fit the number of elements into an `int` by using user-defined datatypes. Jeff Hammond's [BigMPI](https://github.com/jeffhammond/BigMPI) to the rescue.

Comment: how does one make a new datatype, for example in scatterv I'd like to pass a variables number of doubles. should I use an extended datatype with the greatest common denominator. Is that separate from BigMPI? BigMPi seems to throw away scatterv and implement them naively, in terms of receive and send.

Comment: The datatype should be a contiguous one with size that divides all the sizes. If the sizes are co-prime, your only choice is to do individual Isend/Irecv. Besides, the `MPI_Scatterv' implementation for bigger messages in most MPI libraries is not that different from what BigMPI does.

Answer (score 1):

why not distribute your scatters as well so that int type will be enough ?

You can consider MPI processes running as the nodes of a Tree. And have the intermediate Tree Nodes have their own scatter/gathers of the corresponding sub-Trees.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom MPI datatype to represent a block of LONGs.  Displacements and counts would then be multiples of that block size.